# HAVE TO SAVE DATA IN A TABLE VIEW CELL WHICH IS IN TEXT FIELDS BY CLICKING A BUTTON

Tags: ios

i have taken two view controllers in first i have a table view and in second one i have text fields 
[image]

now by clicking the add button in second view the data entered in text fields should be saved in first view controller by creating a new cell

What methods should be used and code should be written in add button action

Comment: can you show your tried code....

Comment: i didn't try any code i am a beginner

Comment: welcome to iOS domain , if I start to explain the answer related to answer , it takes too long , for ex, in here in your navigation is wrong, apart from if you want to pass the data from VC2 to VC1 is not a easy thing to pass, we need to use (Singleton, localdatabase or Bean object class, etc.), so which one I explain in here.., better you need to try in google once

Comment: Actually my task is 1.To create a contact list which should have a image,number and name 2. By clicking on it a new view should be shown only for displaying that particular contact 3. Then a add button should be there in 1st view for creating a new contact and on clicking on a image view it should go in to gallery 4. After adding the details we have to click a save button below and the data given above should be saved in 1st view as a contact . I have done all the process except saving this data i have googled and searched in youtube but i didn't get any solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second view, after clicking the add button, make one dictionary as

```
NSDictionary * dataDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
         @"Name", NameTextField.text,
         @"MobileNo", MobileNoTextField.text,
         @"EmailId", EmailId.text, nil];
```

Save this dictionary to NSUserDefaults as below

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:dataDic forKey:@"dataDic"];
```

Now in the first view get back the data

```
NSDictionary * myDictionary = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryForKey:@"dictionaryKey"];
```

Comment: @BalajiPraveen You have to reload the data of the table view based on the dictionary or array. as described in answer.

Comment: In first view where should i write this code i have a table view and also created an xib cell

Comment: You can write in ViewWillAppear. After that reload the data.

Comment: @priyabagrecha -- your userdefault value can hold mutiple objects

Answer (score 0):

```
//create propertes in .h of tableviewclass
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *mobile;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *email;

//and pass it like this
    TableviewClassVC *tableviewClass = [[TableviewClassVC alloc] init];
    tableviewClass.name=self.nameTextfield.text ;
    tableviewClass.mobile=self.mobileTextfield.text ;
    tableviewClass.email=self.mailfield.text ;


//and push it 

self.navigationController pushViewController:tableviewClass animated:YES];
```

then u can use data to show in  tableview. thanks

Comment: What's that? Try to explain it as well. For sure it'll not help the user

Comment: @jagveeer -- why you increased the memory of stack

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik why it inreased the memory stack, can u explain pls